# How to target links with print.css

Tags: css

For whatever reason, my links font are not changing at all. When I load in my browser, the only font messed up is my links! Print Preview in Chrome is messing up print css.

any ideas?

```
@media print {
    body, p, a, a:link, a:visited {

            font-size: 7pt !important; 
    }
  }
```

In Google Chrome, my hyperlinks are blue and font-size has not changed at all.

Answer:  USe - *{transition:none!important}.

Comment: Have you tried just `a` without `:link` or `:visited`?

Comment: i have.  body, p, a, a:link, a:visited {

         font-size: 7pt !important; 
    }

Comment: In the code above you haven't got plain old `a`.

Comment: i added it afterwards, it seems to affect only chrome. prints fine in firefox

Comment: It's worth putting a detail like that in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need all that extra Jazz with body / p tags.

Also, never a bad idea to give this `<a>` tag a selector. *Easier to target directly.*

```
@media print{
       a.selector:hover { font-size: 7pt; }
}
```

If it's absolutely *all* links:

```
@media print{ 
    a:active,a:hover,a:link,a:visited{font-size:7pt}
 }
```

*Please provide code that won't override if still having issue.*

Comment: Hey I went to that college for a few courses alongggg time ago!

Comment: Did you try the adjustment snippet(s) I gave you? Browser clear / cache?

Comment: i did. in fact, emulation mode in chrome, it looks just fine. it's only when i do print preview and print it. that the hyperlinks are messed up.  Firefox and IE work fine.

Comment: hey, i found the answer - http://wisercoder.com/print-preview-significantly-different-inspector-chrome/.   had to add - *{transition:none!important}. wow, i hate you google!